# Can propositional functions be categorized as tautologies, contradictions or contingencies by themselves?

Tags: logic

I've read that compound propositions are classified as either tautologies, contradictions or contingencies, depending on whether they are always true, always false or dependent on the variable.

Is it possible to apply the same concept to individual propositional functions rather than compound propositions, so that if a given propositional function of the variable $x$ takes the truth value T for every possible value of $x,$ then it is called a tautology, etc.

I feel like we should be able to do this, but I think my question is more about whether such a use of terminology is "acceptable" or "by the rules" as far as mathematical conventions are concerned.

Comment: What is an "individual propositional functions"?

Comment: Maybe you are considering propositional variables: $p,q,...$

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity. By compound propositions I meant the propositions that are connected via connectors such as in conditional statements such as "If p, then q" etc. Here the propositional variables are p and q as you've mentioned. By "an individual propositional function" I mean any p(x) where p(x) is a individual/single propositional function that does not involve any connectors hence not a compound proposition and the truth value of p(x) is dependent on the value of x.

Comment: The answer is yes. Tautology: $p \lor \lnot p$. Contra: $p \land \lnot p$. Contingent: $p \lor q$.

Comment: Of what type are the allowed values of "x" in your so-called propositional functions $p(x)$?

Comment: If there are not connectives, what is left is a formula made of a single occurrence of a prop variable.

Comment: If you replace prop variables: $p,q,...$ with "propositional functions": $\phi(x), \psi(x),...$ the problem still stand. How to express a contradiction without $\lnot$? a tautology without connectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to apply the same concept to individual propositional functions rather than compound propositions

Isn't this a false dichotomy? A **propositional function** is something like `R(x)`, while a **compound proposition** is something like `Q ∨ ∃x R(x)`. The former cannot be a (propositional-logic) tautology since its truth-functional form is just the **propositional variable** `P` (which might stand for `pigs can fly`); however, if by “tautology” you mean a logic formula that is true under every possible interpretation, then yes the propositional function `x=x` is a “tautology”.